# Magento 2 - How to create custom files and get their URL?

Tags: magento2, pdf, magento2.3

I have a custom module which should create a pdf file each time a user clicks a button. Ideally the PDF would be created in `MyVendor_MyModule::pdfFiles/mypfd123.pdf` but it can be created anywhere else if it can't be done inside my module folder.

after creating that pdf, I would need to get its url in order to open a new tab showing it.

I already know how to create the file, I just don't know how to tell magento that I want to place it in my module folder. Also I don't know how to get its absolute URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing things correctly, it's better to not create a new folder in the **Magento Module architecture**, pdfFiles doesn't exist. I suggest you create it in the `web` folder instead.

To do that :

1. create your **pdf** folder inside web module folder : `app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/web/pdfFiles`.
2. create function in your block to get the pdf path:

   `app/code/Vendor/Modulename/Block/Blockname.php`

   ```
   protected $_moduleReader;

   public function __construct(
       ....
       \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader $moduleReader
   ) {
       ....
       $this->_moduleReader = $moduleReader;
   }

   public function getPdfDirectory(){
       $path = $this->_moduleReader->getModuleDir(
           \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir::MODULE_VIEW_DIR,
           'Vendor_Modulename'
       );
       return $path."/frontend/web/pdfFiles/" ;
   }
   ```
3. Then you get that pdf path like this :

   ```
   $block->getPdfDirectory() // /var/www/magentoProject/app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/web/pdfFiles/
   ```

   <sup>Good luck.</sup>